# Where to find the CPU and memory utilization on New Relic for an AWS lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, newrelic

I keep track of my applications on New Relic. I have a few lambdas that I would like to monitor. Specifically, the CPU and memory utilization. I can't seem to find where that's located in New Relic. It's not in the `ServerlessSample`, `SystemSample`, or `Metrics`. Does anyone know where it's supposed to be, maybe I have something set up wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory can be found in [AwsLambdaInvocation](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/serverless-function-monitoring/aws-lambda-monitoring/ui-data/understand-lambda-data-structure), which is where most of the Lambda monitoring lands. Unfortunately, there is currently no way to measure CPU utilization, but feel free to file a feature request. For additional serverless monitoring questions, we’d love to help you out over on our slack (newrelicusers) or you can always reach out to support directly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It might be helpful to know you can see the designation for any metric you see in a graph by going to 'View Query' from any graph.

[image: screenshot of the NR user interface]

The full NRQL query for the Memory usage chart is

```
SELECT percentile(cwMaxMemoryUsed, 50) as 'Max Memory Used', max(cwMemorySize) as 'Memory Available' FROM AwsLambdaInvocation WHERE (`entityGuid`='[your entity GUID]') SINCE 1800 seconds AGO TIMESERIES EXTRAPOLATE
```